# Calculations inside a repeater (new repeat) control

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

A form in a Orbeon form builder contains a repeater control(new repeat).Suppose there are three text controls on each row(or repeat) of a repeater control(new repeat).first two text controls on each row contains numeric values.I want to bring the product of first two text controls to the third text control at run time without any event.there will be multiple numbers of repeat in the runtime ,i.e the row may increase but for each the calculation much reflect at runtime and for each row product of first two must be viewed on the third one

I used the following codes :

```
if ($quantity castable as xs:double and $price castable as xs:double)
then $quantity * $price
else 'n/a'
```

Its ok with this xpath expression when there is only one row in the repeater control.But on adding new rows ,i.e on increasing the repeat at run time, all results in the controls of third column changes to the else value ("n/a"). This is working only for a single row of a repeater control(new repeat). Because for every repeat the value must be calculated for each row separately.

Answer (score 1):

Assume this is your node which repeats for each row

```
<repeater>
    <quantity></quantity>
    <price></price>
    <product></product>
</repeater>
```

the Xpath expression for calculating the product would be

```
if(../quantity castable as xs:double and  ../price castable as xs:double) 
    then ../quantity * ../price
    else 'N/A'
```

This expression when used in calculate for the `<product>` node results the product on each row and there is no event based action required since this is written on the bind definition of the node.

Hope this answers to all your questions